# How can i print an array passed from a page to FPDF

Tags: php, arrays, fpdf

My fpdf.php file is

```
 <?php
        require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
        $prod_data = array();
        if($_POST['affiliate_pdf']){
            $prod_data = unserialize($_POST['affiliate_pdf']);
        }
        class PDF extends FPDF
        {
        public $prod_data;

       public function createData($input){
            $this->prod_data = $input;
        }
        function Header()
        {
            // Page header
            global $title;
            $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
            $w = $this->GetStringWidth($title)+6;
            $this->SetX((210-$w)/2);
            $this->SetDrawColor(0,80,180);
            $this->SetFillColor(230,230,0);
            $this->SetTextColor(220,50,50);
            $this->SetLineWidth(1);
            $this->Cell($w,9,$title,1,1,'C',true);
            $this->Ln(10);
            // Save ordinate
            $this->y0 = $this->GetY();
        }
        // Load data
        function LoadData($file)
        {
            // Read file lines
            $lines = file($file);
            $data = array();
            foreach($lines as $line)
                $data[] = explode(';',trim($line));
            return $data;
        }
        }
        $pdf = new PDF();
        // Column headings
        $title = 'Title';
        $header = array('AFFILIATE CHANNELS', 'TOTAL CHANNEL REVENUE', 'TOTAL  SHARE OF REVENUE', 'TOTAL AFFILIATE SHARE OF REVENUE');
        // Data loading
        $data = $pdf->LoadData('countries.txt');
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->Cell(10,10,'Affiliate Name', 0,0,'L');
        $pdf->Output();
        ?>
```

`affiliate_pdf` is my array which i am passing to fpdf.php . Here i want to use its values. So, i just want to ask , how can i print this array in `$pdf->Cell` or can i write it at any other place.

Mainly i just want to print its value on this pdf. It may be in any array format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [print_r()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). By defaut, it print array values but you can set a param to return values.

```
$pdf->Cell(10,10,print_r($your_array, true), 0,0,'L');
```